# El botón "submit" no funciona en formulario

Tags: php, html, formularios, submit, form-submit

Tengo un formulario de contacto en HTL, cuyo botón "submit" no realiza ninguna acción. El formulario se encuentra contenido dentro de una modal. Intenté sacarlo de la modal a una `<section>` dentro del *Body* pero sigue sin querer funcionar. Intenté también cambiar a `<button type="submit">` sin éxito.

Mi código *HTML*:

```html
<form name="Contacto"  action="enviar.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sexo" placeholder="Sexo">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono" placeholder="Celular">
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="estado" placeholder="Estado">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <select class="form-control" name="seguro" form="Contacto">
                <option value="vida">Seguro de Vida</option>
                <option value="medico">Gastos Médicos</option>
                <option value="automovil">Seguro para automóvil</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <a href="#" class="btn-formulario-slider background-second-color box-shadow padding-15px margin-top-30px">Enviar</a> -->
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn-formulario-slider background-second-color box-shadow padding-15px margin-top-30px">
</form>
```

Comment: ¿Tendrás algún js anulando el `submit()`?, lo digo por que si ejecuto el snnipet aquí si que lo intenta procesar

Comment: Intenta cambiar el `<input type="submit">` por un `<button type="submit">`

Comment: Efectivamente, existía un JS que bloqueba el submit(), lo resolví como me comentaron cambiando el <input> por <button> e indicándole que hiciera el submit con una función OnClick, gracias por los consejos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existía un JS bloquenaod la acción de submit(). Haciendo un poco de research lo resolví de la siguiente manera; sustituyendo el input por un botón e indicándole la acción submit en el atributo Onclick.Anexando también un alert para confirmar el envío.

```html
<div class="modal contact-modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content margin-top-150px">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-lg-5">
                        <img src="assets/img/form_contacto.jpg" alt="pedro calderón contacto">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <div class="padding-30px">
                            <h3 class="padding-bottom-35px form-h3">¿Cómo podemos ayudarte?</h3>
                            <?php   
                            if (isset ($_POST['nombre'])) {

                                    $para      = 'micorreo@midominio.com';
                                    $titulo = 'Contacto desde el sitio web de Pedro Calderón';
                                    $mensaje = 'Nombre: ' . $_POST['nombre']. "\n" .'Correo: ' . $_POST['correo']. "\n" .'Teléfono: ' . $_POST['telefono']. "\n" .'Sexo: ' . $_POST['sexo']. "\n" .'Ciudad: ' . $_POST['ciudad']. "\n" .'Seguro: ' . $_POST['seguro'];
                                    $cabeceras = 'From: ' . $_POST['nombre'] . "\r\n" .
                                        'Reply-To:' . $_POST['correo']. "\r\n" .
                                        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

                                    mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
                            }
                            ?>
                    <?php if (!isset ($_POST['nombre'])) {?>
                            <form id="Contacto" name="Contacto" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>#Enviado">
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="correo" placeholder="Correo">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sexo" placeholder="Sexo">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               <div class="form-row">
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ciudad" placeholder="Ciudad">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" name="seguro" form="Contacto">
                                          <option value="Vida">Seguro de Vida</option>
                                          <option value="Médico">Gastos Médicos</option>
                                          <option value="Automóvil">Seguro para automóvil</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               <!-- <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn-formulario-slider background-second-color box-shadow padding-15px margin-top-30px"> -->
                                <button type="submit" class="btn-formulario-slider background-second-color box-shadow padding-15px margin-top-30px" onclick="document.forms.Contacto.submit();"><a onClick="show()">Enviar</a></button>
                            </form>
                        <?php } else echo '
                        <div>
                            <h3>Mensaje Enviado</h3>
                        </div>
                        ';?>
                            
                        <script>
                            function show() {
                              alert("Mensaje enviado.\nGracias por contactarnos, en breve nos contactaremos contigo para otorgarte mayor información.");
                            }
                        </script>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```